# Why Won't Any C# JSON Class Generators Process this JSON Object?

Tags: c#, json

I've tried 3 different JSON class generators, but I get an error when I try to generate a C# class from the following JSON output:

```
{
"status": "REQUEST_STATUS",
"language": "DOCUMENT_LANGUAGE",
"url": "REQUESTED_URL",
"text": "DOCUMENT_TEXT",
"entities": [
    "entity": {
        "type": "DETECTED_TYPE",
        "relevance": "DETECTED_RELEVANCE",
        "count": "DETECTED_COUNT",
        "text": "DETECTED_ENTITY"
        "disambiguated": {
            "name": "DISAMBIGUATED_ENTITY",
            "subType": "ENTITY_SUBTYPE",
            "website": "WEBSITE",
            "geo": "LATITUDE LONGITUDE",
            "dbpedia": "LINKED_DATA_DBPEDIA",
            "yago": "LINKED_DATA_YAGO",
            "opencyc": "LINKED_DATA_OPENCYC",
            "umbel": "LINKED_DATA_UMBEL",
            "freebase": "LINKED_DATA_FREEBASE",
            "ciaFactbook": "LINKED_DATA_FACTBOOK",
            "census": "LINKED_DATA_CENSUS",
            "geonames": "LINKED_DATA_GEONAMES",
            "musicBrainz": "LINKED_DATA_MUSICBRAINZ",
            "crunchbase": "CRUNCHBASE_WEB_LINK",
        },
        "quotations": [
            {
                "quotation": "ENTITY_QUOTATION"
            }
        ],
        "sentiment": {
            "type": "SENTIMENT_LABEL",
            "score": "SENTIMENT_SCORE",
            "mixed": "SENTIMENT_MIXED"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The error is on the following line, at the bracket:

```
"entities": [
```

But all the examples I have found using the above two tools do have examples of using arrays like mine, so why does mine cause an exception.  The exception is, "Invalid character and line 7 position 17.

If I change the straight brackets to currly brackets it will generate but that's changing the class, right?

Comment: you can't have named array keys.

Comment: It's invalid JSON, plain and simple.

Comment: I suggest you to check your json data here: http://jsonlint.com/ As others' said, it's not a valid json pattern.

Comment: The problem is this sequence `[ "entity" :`.  There is no way for that to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

things inside of arrays dont themselves have names so just change

```
"entities": [
   "entity": {
      "type": "DETECTED_TYPE",
```

to

```
"entities": [ {
   "type": "DETECTED_TYPE",
```

Comment: OK, I'm new to JSON (obvious); I'm using a commercial API and just copied what they said was the output: http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity/urls.html#rurl 
Not good for some one learning!  Thanks a bunch. I can't believe the speed these answers came in!  Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @RichardGolko - The JSON spec is at json.org.  Accept no substitute!